# .htaccess, поддомен

Tags: .htaccess, поддомены

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Этот код великолепно работает, пока использую на сайте domain.com, но когда его же использую на tests.domain.com, то он пишет ошибку 404, я так предполагаю, что ошибка в `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, подскажите, если знаете, как исправить! При этом tests.domain.com/test1.php - заходит, а на tests.domain.com/test1 - нет. На domain.com все работало и работает до сих пор без проблем, я так предполагаю мне либо в техподдержку хостера писать либо делать все без поддоменнов

Comment: @Minetrader, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: К сожалению, ответа нет :(

Answer (score 2):

Строкой

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
```

вы ставите условие, что на сервере не найдется файла test1.php, когда вводите адрес tests.domain.com/test1. Но файл tests.domain.com/test1.php, судя по описанию задачи, существует. Следовательно, строка

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

не выполняется. 
Пройдя все строки htaccess без переходов, сервер хочет найти файл с именем test1, без расширения. Не находит его и отдает 404 ошибку. Возможно, на главном домене у вас иная структура директорий.

Comment: Ваш ответ нашел ошибку мою в описании моей ошибки, но, к сожалению, её не исправил т.к. Это были мои эксперименты с файлом, не давшие результата. Коротко говоря: не посмотрел, что отправляю как ошибку.

Comment: @Minetrader, посмотрите логи на сервере. Возможно, вы что-то нам не договариваете или уже "наэксперементировали" что-то уникальное. Второй вариант - поставьте в самой последней строке в конце [R,L] и посмотрите в браузере, какие заголовки отправляются и какая страница открывается.

Работают ли вообще RewriteRule на вашем поддомене?